# Reading XMLs and sending to REST Endpoint with basic authorization using Talend

Tags: xml, rest, talend

Requirement: The job should take input from a XML file and post it to the REST endpoint that has Basic Authorization (username and password).
How can I achieve this using Talend?

Comment: Documentation of tFileInputXml and tREST should get you started

Comment: tFileInputXML is used to parse the XML file while reading but in my case the whole file should be read as a string. I tried with tFileInputRaw but it has Object as datatype and the tRest does not have Authorization option. tRESTClient has that option but it takes body as Document datatype. tConvertType aparantly doesn't convert object to document. The problem seems too easy to have such relatively complex conversions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tFileInputRaw` along with `tREST`. Just put a `tMap` between them which casts the object to a string:

```
tFileInputRaw -- tMap -- tREST
```

In tMap you can do `(String)rowX.content` as an expression of the output column which is a String.

For authorization with `tREST`, you add an "Authorization" http header, which has a value of "`Basic xxxx`" where xxxx is a base64 encoded string of your user and password separated by a column "`user:password`"